# return foo only if all joined bar have the same column value

Tags: sql, informix

I have 2 tables `foo` and `bar`, there is a one to many relation between the two. I want to get a list of foos where all the corresponding bars have a column `status = 'CLOSED'`. How should I write that query?

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM foo f
JOIN bar b ON b.foo_bk = f.bk
WHERE b.status = 'CLOSED'
```

The current query will return the `foo` even if it has one `bar` with a different `status` value. I have been looking at `CASE` and `IF` queries but I don't know how to get them to work for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add subquery as below

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM foo f
JOIN bar b ON b.foo_bk = f.f_bk
WHERE b.status = 'CLOSED'
AND not exists (select 1
                from bar b2
                where b2.foo_bk = f.f_bk
                and b.status <> 'CLOSED')
```

Comment: @LisaMM I modified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT f.* FROM foo f
JOIN bar b ON b.foo_bk = f.f_bk
WHERE f.f_bk IN (SELECT b.bk FROM bar b WHERE b.status = 'CLOSED')
AND f.f_bk NOT IN (SELECT b.bk FROM bar b WHERE b.status <> 'CLOSED')
```

This query will give you all the rows that exist in bar with status 'CLOSED', while omitting rows with other statuses.